# How to connect 2 access points where one of them is not connected to the wired network

Tags: wireless-networking

Our business current runs Cisco 1240AG access points.  We are going to be upgrading soon, but need some help on a connection that has failed.

We have an access point that is connected to the wired LAN then there is another access point that is connected to an unmanaged switch that only communicates to a few devices.  (the reasoning for the access point is that it is too long of a distance to one of our edge switches to run a hard connection.)

Somehow the one access point was getting a connection from the one that is LAN connected and sending a signal to the other.  This access point is now failed and I am trying to figure out how to replace it.

I didn't think this was possible since in a bridge connection both AP's would need to be physically connected to the actual network.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the second 1240AG was configured *not* as an AP, but as a client (station), which Cisco *apparently* calls "[workgroup bridge](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wireless/aironet-1200-series/68472-configure-wgb-00.html)" mode (elsewhere I've seen it called "Station (WDS)" or "WDS-Bridge" mode). In this mode, the device doesn't send its own 'signal', just connects to a remote AP.

Another possibility is that the second 1240AG was configured as a [repeater](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/12-4_3g_JA/configuration/guide/ios1243gjaconfigguide/s43hot.html), which allows it to continue working as an AP (at the cost of reduced speed).